# How to prevent Excel from changing long numbers to E format and rounding to zero

Tags: excel, csv, otrs

When I export search result to CSV file from OTRS and open the CSV file in Excel, I get the ticket number as: 2,01101E+15 .

No problem until now, but when I change the number to text field the last digit of ticket number is rounded to zero. e.g if I have a ticket number 123456789 then excel changes it to 123456780.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: This does not appear to be related to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is actually only one way in Excel to do this.
Create an empty sheet -> Choose File->Import->CSV and select your CSV file. The delimiter should be a semicolon and fields are enclosed by ". In the next step you have to choose "Text" for the Ticket# column.

This is a very annoying Excel "bug". Another way to do this would be a macro, but running macros is often not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Set output in search to CSV, etc.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Change System ID on SYSCONFIG::Core in a value with one digit  Example: 1 or 2 or 3 ...9

This will short the length of the ticket number and will be displayed normally on .csv file.

Do not put like 01 or 02. It will cause the same error.